# The data.table package syntax: parentheses, .SD and .SDcols

Tags: r, syntax, data.table

I'm an R newbie and I'm trying to understand the syntax of this line.  I understand what it is doing, but I do not understand how it is expressed:

```
plms[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, str_trim), .SDcols = cols]
```

`plms` is a data.table.  `cols` is a list of the names of all character columns in `plms`.  This line applies `str_trim` to all character columns in `plms`.  However, I do not understand:

1) why `(cols)` exists in brackets.

2) what `.SD` and `.SDcols` mean.  Neither `.SD` nor `.SDcols` have been used already in the script - they are both mentioned first here.  What is the significance of the dot which prefixes them?

I'm also a little unsure of the `:=` operator - I gather it has an extended meaning with data.tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check out the [intro vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for `data.table`, and some of the [highest rated answers on the `data.table` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdata.table%5D+is%3Aquestion&tab=votes) on stack overflow. this will help you along the way. then, if you're still stuck, feel free to follow up & we'll be more ready to nudge you along :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @Hopkins, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

1) In R `()` is a function and can be overriden, i.e. you can assign to it different behaviour. You may notice when you execute `(a <- 1)` the console is printing `1`, i.e. this behaviour can be remade. In the context of `data.table` and your example please see below.

At first let's prepare the `plms` data table:

```
set.seed(123)
plms <- data.table(
  a = sample(c("A", "B ", "C ", " D "), 5, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(c("A", "B  ", "C ", " D "), 5, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(c("A", "B ", "C ", " D "), 5, replace = TRUE)
)
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
plms
#     a   b   c
# 1:  B    A  D 
# 2:  D   C   B 
# 3:  B   D   C 
# 4:  D   C   C 
# 5:  D  B     A
```

As you can see data table with trailing spaces generated. Then lets apply your code:

```
plms[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, str_trim), .SDcols = cols]
plms
# a b c
# 1: B A D
# 2: D C B
# 3: B D C
# 4: D C C
# 5: D B A
```

Trailing spaces removed - OK. It means that `data.table` redifined functionality of `()` - it take the column names from the `cols` vector and assign the column-wise`strtrim` result to these columns.

Now without parentheses:

```
plms[, cols := lapply(.SD, str_trim), .SDcols = cols]
plms
# a   b   c      cols
# 1:  B    A  D  B,D,B,D,D
# 2:  D   C   B  A,C,D,C,B
# 3:  B   D   C  D,B,C,C,A
# 4:  D   C   C  B,D,B,D,D
# 5:  D  B     A A,C,D,C,B
```

In fact it means you created column `cols` and assigned a `list` to this column.

2) `.SD` - is an internal read-only symbol (in fact `data.table` object)

> .SD is a data.table containing the Subset of x's Data for each group, excluding any columns used in by (or keyby).

you can the data below:

```
plms[, lapply(.SD, print), .SDcols = cols]
# [1] "B "  " D " "B "  " D " " D "
# [1] "A"   "C "  " D " "C "  "B  "
# [1] " D " "B "  "C "  "C "  "A"  
# a   b   c
# 1:  B    A  D 
# 2:  D   C   B 
# 3:  B   D   C 
# 4:  D   C   C 
# 5:  D  B     A
```

As you can see the result of applying `print` column-wise to `.SD` shows the selected columns by `SDcols`.

`[]` is redifined as well and one of the arguments of this function is `.SDcols` which is used to select columns for the `.SD` data table. Please see below the documentation.

> .SDcols specifies the columns of x to be included in the special
>   symbol .SD which stands for Subset of data.table. May be character
>   column names or numeric positions. This is useful for speed when
>   applying a function through a subset of (possible very many) columns;
>   e.g., DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="x,y", .SDcols=301:350].

3) `:=` is a function as well (you can see help on it with `?":="`. Main idea of this function is that the data are modified inside the object (by reference):

```
plms[, a := "x"]
plms
#    a   b   c
# 1: x   A  C 
# 2: x  D   B 
# 3: x   A  B 
# 4: x B    D 
# 5: x  C   B
```

Usually R works by value and there is no modification of the object during function execution (functional approach: function should not change argument during execution).

Fundamentally this is somehow controversial point of `data.table` package as change of the internal state  of an object may lead to hardly identifying mistakes and difficutlies with debugging, however providing superior speed and smaller memory required for handling in comparison with e.g. `base::data.frame`.